# htaccess: redirect if not match

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I want to forward everything on site X (http://example.com) to Site Y (http://destinationwebsite.com)
except "PAGEX.aspx"

```
(http://example.com/PAGEX.aspx?callback=7259%2F7062434327_9fbc6da0cd)
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?PAGEX.aspx$
 RewriteRule .* http://destinationwebsite.com [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you prepend `!` to your regex in the RewriteRule it will act as a negation.